# Check if a request to iis 5 has been arrived

Tags: iis, iis-5

I have two servers on the same internal network the first server that has the role of a client makes HTTP requests to a web service that resides in the second server. The second server has IIS 5 to response in client requests. I have occasionally requests to the web services that has no response at all. How can I find in the IIS 5 if a specific request has been arrived in the IIS? I have to find if there is connectivity problem (network issues) or IIS or maybe application (web service) issues
Thanks

Comment: You wont be able to network related issues on machine where you have web service because in case of network issue request will never reach destination. For application related issues you need to handle exceptions and write exception details to file. You will get broad idea of issue by checking IIS logs.

Comment: Ok.... I will be more clear... How can I match a request from the client with a log line in IIS? In the mean time I run a ping utility (hrping) from client that ping repeatedly the server. It runs for 2 days and there wasn't a lost packet while there were 30 requests (from 2.000) from client that they didn't have response. So there isn't network issue... and every request must have a matched line in iis log.